# How to find coefficient from gradient vector?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If $E= (3x+2y)I_x + (2-ax+2z)I_y + (2y-z)I_z$ is a gradient of vector. Find $a$ where $$Ix,Iy,Iz$$ are vector components like $i,j,k$

[image]

Comment: Do you mean that $I_x$ is the unit vector in the $x$ direction, $\hat{x}$?

Comment: no i_x, i_y, i_z are vector components like i,j,k

Comment: Use the property that curl of gradient is 0

Comment: thanks really. if it was the curl above (curl of some function)? how would I find a?

Comment: $i,j,k$ usually mean the same thing as the unit vectors $\hat{x},\hat{y},\hat{z}$. If this is not the case, then the question is unclear. Components of *what* vector?

Answer (score 0):

If $E$ is the gradient of a scalar (not vector), then its rotor must be zero, i.e.

$$\nabla \times E = 0 \; .$$

In particular, the $z$-component of the rotor becomes

$$(\nabla \times E)_z = \partial_xE_y - \partial_yE_x = -a-2 \; .$$

This is zero provided $a = -2$.